# Why is my C++ program opening in text editor after compilation?

Tags: linux, shell, build, cinnamon, binary-files

I've just compiled a C++ program - which is *not* a console program, but instead, graphical and using gtkmm.

After building with g++, I can launch it by typing ./program from the terminal. However, if I try to execute it by double-click through the File Manager, it won't run - opens in Text Editor instead. It doesn't even ask me if I want to execute or open in text editor, like it would if this were a bash script for example.

The executable bit is set for this file.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What command did you use to compile?

Comment: @DrZoo `g++ randolfi.cpp -o randolfi` with a long list of include paths and libraries (using `-I` and `-l`, respectively) from gtkmm and dependencies.

Comment: How many files do you have?

Comment: You should do something like `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld 'pkg-config gtkmm-X.X --cflags --libs'` Where X and X is the version, for example `gtkmm-3.0` idk what the current version is. Substitute the `'` with a `. I only used them so it wouldn't format it

Comment: @DrZoo Hm, didn't think about piping output from pkg-config directly to the build command. But I was indeed using it, only I was copy-pasting the output. Anyway, my problem is not related to the build process at all. It runs from terminal, and also from a desktop launcher I made.

Comment: I'm just unsure if you're missing a step. You should do g++ compiling twice. Once for the .cpp, then once for the .o file, then do `./program`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, from reading here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335763/154671), this is simply not possible anymore in GNOME Files, and by extension, Nemo, which is the file browser I'm using.